# Set the Scrollbar width of a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I'm working on an app for a mobile device and would like to make a datagrid scrollbar button larger to enhance the touch screen usability.   I do not want to alter the system settings windows display properties as this will affect the device as a whole.

Is there an easy way to alter the width of the scrollbar on a datagrid view?

Comment: jasonk: i put together a very simple sample of a custom grid scroller here: http://www.mediafire.com/?nzjnmmjji31 (I also added the link to my answer. Let me know if you want to pursue the idea further.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you'll have to roll your own. Not to worry though, it shouldn't be that hard. i say shouldn't because it's been a while since i've done .NET CF UI (shooting from the hip) but have implemented a custom scroller for a .NET 2.0 touch screen UI.

That said, here's what you need to do:

- Hide the scroll bars in the grid view
- Create a custom control which hosts two buttons, one top, one bottom
- Handle the clicks on those buttons and forward them as scroll up/down calls to the grid view

That's the simple way. You don't get the dragging and stuff but that's rarely useful in such a tiny UI anyway. You could also put in later if you want.

Caveat: The grid view might not have ScrollUp/Down APIs exposed. In that case you'll need to overlay your custom control on top of the grid view which will have the scroll bars shown. You hide the built-in scroll bars with your custom control and instead of calling ScrollUp/Down you post windows messages to the area behind your custom control to "fake" clicks and get the grid view to move around the way you like.

Hmm. i was assuming .NET Compact Framework since you mentioned it's for a mobile device... Is it CF? If not, everything ought to be a little easier.

EDIT

Basic sample of [custom grid scrolling here!](http://www.mediafire.com/?nzjnmmjji31)

Comment: It is actually running full Windows XP, Vista or 7.  The display screen is only 5" though.

Answer (score 2):

```cs
FieldInfo fi = dataGridView1.GetType().GetField( "m_sbVert", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance );

( ( VScrollBar ) fi.GetValue( dataGridView1 ) ).Width = 50;

fi = ultraGrid1.GetType().GetField( "m_sbHorz", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance );

( ( HScrollBar ) fi.GetValue( ultraGrid1 ) ).Height = 0;
```

Where 50 is the vertical scrollbar width and 0 is the horizontal scrollbar height.

```cs
using System.Reflection;
```

all at the beginning of your form.

It works for `WinCE 5.0`.